# Weder waren den jungen Leuten die Volksvertreter volksnah genug, noch konnten sie die Parteien gut genug voneinander unterscheiden

Tags: sentence-structure

Representatives were not close or popular to people! Why "den jungen Leuten" is dativ?

Comment: Close TO WHOM? And "to whom" is dativ.

Comment: "Den jungen Leuten" means "from the perspective of the younger people" here, or perhaps you could say "For the young people, the representatives were not suficiently approachable". Does this help explaining the Dativ?

Comment: @Eller. I think you are mistaken here. You are right that it would be "close to whom - wem nahe?". But the word is "volksnah" here, so "close to the people". The "den jungen Leuten" has a different function, see my comment above.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Oh, you're right. My fault, haven't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 11):

Dativ is used here to express in whose perspective the situation is seen as xyz.

> Dem Wanderer war der Berg zu steil.
>
> Dem Lehrer war die Klasse zu laut.
>
> Der Tante war der Kaffee zu stark.
>
> Dem Kapitän war der Wind nicht kräftig genug, darum verschob er das Auslaufen.
>
> Den jungen Leuten waren die Volksvertreter nicht volksnah genug.

It is always "The teacher thought that..." or "From my aunt's perspective...", "The skipper's feeling was that..." and so on. Or simply: "For the teacher...", "For the younger people..." - which makes *Dativ* somehow a natural case to be used as a substitute for the lexicalized expressions.

Note that this expression (Dativ + sein) is used only in cases of comparative judgement (i.e. judgement against any supposed minimal or maximal requirement or value):

> zu steil
>
> zu süß
>
> kräftig genug
>
> süß genug

You may not use *Dativ + sein* without such implicit comparative judgement:

> <strike>Dem Onkel war die Suppe salzig / warm / würzig</strike>

But with *genug* or *zu* it is possible:

> Dem Onkel war die Suppe warm / salzig / würzig **genug**.

(His minimum requirements were met.)

> Der Tante war der Kaffee **zu** heiß / süß / dünn.

(Values were higher than tolerable for her.)

Without such comparative judgement you would use other verbs - and the case they happen to require:

> Die Tante fand den Kaffee aromatisch. (Nom.)
>
> Dem Onkel schien die Suppe fad. (Dat.)
>
> Die jungen Leute hielten die Volksvertreter für unnahbar. (Nom.)
>
> Dem Wanderer kam der Berg hoch vor. (Dat.)
>
> Den Richter dünkte die Zeugenaussage zweifelhaft. (Akk.)

---

Nachtrag: Aus einer Seitendiskussion (siehe Kommentare) erwächst noch die Einsicht, dass "Dativ + sein" noch in einer weiteren Klasse von Wendungen verwendet werden kann:

> Du bist mir ein Schelm!
>
> Du bist mir vielleicht einer!
>
> Das ist mir ja eine schöne Bescherung!
>
> Du bist mir lieb und teuer.
>
> Der ist mir ein freier Mann, der ohne Kraftstoff fahren kann.*

<sub>* Ich habe Tofros Beispiel aus den Kommentaren im Geiste der *political correctness* etwas abgewandelt und modernisiert, das Motiv der Knechtschaft bzw. physischen Abhängigkeit aber beibehalten.</sub>

Man beachte aber: Dies geht nur mit "mir".

> <strike>Du bist ihm vielleicht einer!</strike>
>
> Sie sind ihnen ein Schelm!

sind in alltäglicher Verwendung nicht mehr denkbar, außer natürlich wenn man Spiel und Scherz mit Sprache treibt. "Der ist mir ein freier Mann..." und "Du bist mir lieb und teuer" gehören außerdem in ein lyrisches Sprachregister, das im Alltag kaum auftreten wird.

---

This was an ad-hoc explanation. If someone has a more solid theory: welcome!

Comment: very clear Christian .... appreciate it

Comment: This specific case of dative is called *dativus iudicantis*.

Comment: @Tofro: Oh, wie hübsch. - Da drängt sich dem Leser doch gleich die Folgefrage auf: Gibt es eine ähnliche Konstruktion wohl auch im Lateinischen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *ille mihi non est liber cui mulier imperat* ist auch einer. "Der ist mir kein freier Mann, dem eine Frau befiehlt"

Comment: @Tofro. Und schwupps haben wir ein Beispiel, wo "Dativ + sein" auch ohne "zu" oder "genug" verwendet werden kann. Hm... Du bist mir ein Schelm!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *Du bist mir lieb und teuer* ist ein besserer, "deutscherer"

Comment: @Tofro - Verflixt... meine ganze schöne Theorie bröckelt.